# How to change v-data-table row height

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a problem with a v-data-table, I want to decrease the height of rows to match dense. I tried to set negative margin for each template but it doesn't work. I tried a lot of things but i didn't find any solution.

Thanks!!!!

```css
.cell-height table tbody td, table tbody th {
        margin-top: -15%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
<v-data-table :headers="headersProjectConfig" :items="projectConfig" class="cell-height" hide-default-footer dense>
    <template v-slot:item.isSelected="{ item }">
        <v-checkbox v-if="item.selection"></v-checkbox>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.text="{ item }">
        <span>{{item.text}}</span>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.averageTO="{ item }">
        <v-text-field type="number" hide-details :rules="[v => !!v || 'This field is required']" required></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.averageMargin="{ item }">
        <v-text-field type="number" hide-details :rules="[v => !!v || 'This field is required']" required></v-text-field>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
</template>
```

Comment: your css should be `table.cell-height` not `.cell-height table` (I'm assuming the v-data-table gets converted into a table with those classes on it - if not please show the rendered html)

Comment: Do you also have a working example in codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS for item height is in the `TD`, not the `TR`.

The current version CSS path is:

```css
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td,
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td,
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > td {
  height: 26px;
}
```

You can simplify target by simply adding a class to your `v-data-table`

```html
<v-data-table class='row-height-50' />
```

```css
.v-data-table.row-height-50 td
{
  height: 18px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can just use `css`. `tr` to modify table-row.

```
<style lang="css">
tr{
  height: 70px !important;
}
</style>
```